# Will npm always install the latest available version from the specified range?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Consider I have a package that has `lodash` as a dependency which is specified using the following semver range: `^3.9.1`:

[image]

1). Will npm always install the latest available version that is satisfied by the specified version range (i.e. `3.10.1`), or is there a chance (some edge cases) that some other version would be installed from this range, e.g. `3.9.3`?

2). If answer to the previous question is yes, then why would npm specify dependencies using caret and three version numbers (e.g. `^3.9.1`) and not like `^3` or `3.x`, what purpose does specific minimal version serve?

Comment: Always the most recent major version so in this case yes `3.10.1`. and you can use `~` for the most recent minor version. not specifying a version will bring the latest (`4.5.1`). hope this also answers the second question

Comment: Maybe [Prerelease Tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver#prerelease-tags) is the edge case you're looking for?